# How do I get refresh token from spotipy?

Tags: python, api, spotify, spotipy

I've made python script using **spotipy**, to get songs and their features from **spotify API**. The problem is about that, my requests takes so much time, and its running more than *1hour* (expiration time of access token). How do I use spotipy **refresh token**? It's not refreshing automatically I think beacause script freezes, and when I'm trying get response from Spotify developer console it sends error about expiration of token.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: The documentation reads: "Tokens are refreshed automatically and stored by default in the project main folder." - https://spotipy.readthedocs.io

Comment: So, there must be something other that causes your code to freeze.